# How to emerge world, including overlays, in gentoo

Tags: gentoo, portage

I recently noticed that emerging world does not upgrade packages obtained with layman. I have been syncing with layman, and in fact many of the overlay packages currently installed are no longer in the tree. I suppose I could emerge each package individually to upgrade it, but there has got to be a better way. Here's the relevant part of my current upgrade process:

```
layman --sync-all
emerge --update --deep --with-bdeps=y --newuse --keep-going --complete-graph --verbose-conflicts @world
```

I would think that running emerge like that would at least raise a warning that atoms are in my world file yet not in the portage tree, but I've never seen one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the overlay packages are never stabilized (the `~` is never removed from the arch `KEYWORDS` in the ebuilds). I'm not sure why this isn't being done -- at least in any of the overlay packages I use.

The solution, found in [this gentoo-user mailing list thread](https://archives.gentoo.org/gentoo-user/message/7dfc189c7f5a9437696c1a54e3875db4), is to allow unstable packages from each overlay in `package.accept_keywords`:

```
*/*::overlay-name ~amd64
```